# Linked Server Login Timeout but SqlCmd works

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, connectivity

I've got a SQL 2005 SP4 server that connects to a 2008 SP3 instance via linked servers using the SQL Server server type. Every once in a while, one of those linked servers will start throwing login timeouts. To rule out firewalls, I can RDP to the server and run sqlcmd and get in just fine, even making sure to use the same login. I'm thinking that SQL has somehow cached something that prevents it finding the right address. The remote servername is defined in that machine's host file. So far, only a reboot fixes the issue.

- linked server is setup using remote sql login.
- OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "myserver" returned message "Login timeout expired".
- Bouncing the **service** does not fix the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you doing when you get the timeouts? How do you know it's a timeout versus some other error? Have you tried disabling IPSec? Any login triggers that might slow down the process? If you increase the timeout period, does it stop failing?

Comment: Either submitting a query or testing the linked server. No IPSec, that I know of. No logon triggers. Increased connection timeout does not help. sqlcmd is instantaneous.

Comment: Are you logged in directly on the server (remote desktop) or remote from it? Trying to understand how many hops you are making. And are you finding any errors in the SQL log that match your timeout error?

Comment: RDP to server A with linked server to B. Nothing in error log.

Comment: Could be a Kerberos problem.  Can you verify the necessary SPNs are created?  You can use the new Kerberos tool for SQL Server: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046